# Can an irreducible component of a topological space be covered by the other irreducible components?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and write $X=\bigcup X_i$, where the $X_i$ are the irreducible components of $X$.  Given any $X_i$, I'd like to find a point $x\in X_i$ such that $x\notin \bigcup_{j\ne i}X_j$.  Such a point can always be found if $X$ is Noetherian, because if no such point existed, we would have $X_i=\bigcup_j X_i\cap X_j$, which shows that $X_i$ is reducible.

Suppose now there are infinitely many irreducible components.  Is it possible that one of them is contained in the union of the others?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: I honestly thought that obvious, and I didn't mean to offend you in any way.

Comment: There was a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46719/irreducible-components-of-topological-space) a while back that was never resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question submitting a proof for G. Bresciani's claim in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621466/394668) saying “it's clear the irreducible components are the vertical segments and $[0,1]\times\{0\}$.” (I don't think it's that clear; if the vertical segments and $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ were all open, then if would be immediate thanks to [the bijection between irreducible components of a space and those from an open subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1969679/394668), but the thing is that they are not open in this strange topology.)

Let $I$ be an infinite set. Set $X=I\times I$ and fix $i_0\in I$. Denote $V_i=\{i\}\times I\subset X$, $i\in I$ to the “vertical segments” and $H=I\times\{i_0\}\subset X$ to the “horizontal segment at $i_0$” (this terminology is motivated from the case $I=[0,1]$).

> **Lemma.** Suppose $X$ has a topology such that:
>
> 1. $V_i$ is closed and $V_i':=V_i\setminus \{(i,i_0)\}$ is open,
> 2. the subspaces $H$ and $V_i$, $i\in I$ have the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology), and
> 3. Either $H$ is an irreducible component of $X$ or the following property holds: if $Z\subset X$ is a closed subset such that $(Z\setminus H)\cap V_i$ is finite for all $i$, then $Z\setminus H$ is closed.
>
> Then the irreducible components of $X$ are exactly $H$ and $V_i$, $i\in I$.

> **Corollary.** There is a topological space with an irreducible component contained in the union of the other irreducible components.

*Proof of the corollary.* Suppose we *defined* the topology on $X$ by the rule: a subset $U\subset X$ is open if and only if, for all $i\in I$, the set $U\cap V_i$ (resp., $U\cap H$) is open in $V_i$ (resp., in $H$) with the cofinite topology. This rule defines a family of subsets that is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections and hence defines a topology. We verify the hypotheses of the lemma. On the one hand, points 1 and 3 are obvious. On the other hand, to see point 2, if $F\subset X$ is closed, then $F\subset V_i$ (resp., $F\cap H$) is closed in the cofinite topology of $V_i$ (resp., of $H$) by definition. Conversely, one easily verifies that $X$ is $\mathrm{T}_1$ (finite subsets of $X$ are closed). In particular, so is any finite subset contained in $V_i$ (resp., contained in $H$). Thus, we can apply the lemma to obtain $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$ is a union of irreducible components although $H$ is also another irreducible component of $X$. $\square$

*Proof of the lemma.* Note that $H$ is closed in $X$ (its complementary set, $\bigcup_i V_i'$, is open), and that $V_i$ and $H$ are irreducible (so is any infinite topological space bearing the cofinite topology). We will show they are irreducible components (i.e., maximal in the poset of closed irreducible subsets of $X$).

$H$ is an irreducible component (assume the ‘property’ from point 3 holds): suppose $Z\subset X$ is a closed and irreducible subset such and $H\subset Z$. Note that $Z$ does not contain $V_i$ (if it did, then $Z=V_i\cup (Z\setminus V_i')$ is a union of closed proper subsets); hence, $Z\cap V_i$ is finite. We have $Z=H\cup (Z\setminus H)$, where $Z\setminus H$ is closed (the set $(Z\setminus H)\cap V_i\subset Z\cap V_i$ is finite for all $i\in I$). Therefore, $H=Z$.

$V_i$ is an irreducible component: suppose $Z\subset X$ is a closed and irreducible subset such and $V_i\subset Z$. We know we cannot have $H\subset Z$, whence $H\cap Z$ is finite. Thus, $Z=\bigcup_{(j,i_0)\in H\cap Z} V_j\cap Z$ is a finite disjoint union of closed subsets; hence, $V_i=Z$.

Finally, we show that $H$ and $V_i$, $i\in I$, are all the irreducible components of $X$. Suppose $Z\subset X$ is an irreducible component. Since $V_i'\subset X$ is open, we have that if $Z\cap V_i'$ is non-empty, then it is an irreducible component of $V_i'$ (whence $V_i'\subset Z$; thus, $V_i=Z$). Therefore, either there is $i\in I$ such that $V_i'$ meets $Z$ (in which case $V_i=Z$), or $Z\subset H$ (whence $Z=H$). $\square$